# HiddenHttpMethodFilter configuration without xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How can I implement [HiddenHttpMethodFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) in Spring MVC without having to add entries to my web.xml?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So i came up with solution.

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext aServletContext) throws ServletException
    {       
        registerHiddenFieldFilter(aServletContext);
    }

    private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", new     HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*"); 
    }
}
```

Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply add it in you web.xml as a normal filter, no spring xml configuration required (if not using DelegatingFilterProxy)

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: thanks for answering but idea was that I don't want any xml on my project